# MySQL sometimes shutdown itself at the midnight. Here is the log

Tags: mysql

My MySQL service sometimes shutdown itself at around 2AM of the day. I cannot find which part of this log file explain the cause.

I host it on DigitalOcean. I am not sure is it because of their backup and snapshot things or not.

Please advise.

```
150812  2:27:48 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150812  2:27:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150812  2:27:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150812  2:27:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150812  2:27:48 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150812  2:27:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
InnoDB: mmap(274726912 bytes) failed; errno 12
150812  2:27:48 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150812  2:27:48 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
150812  2:27:48 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150812  2:27:48 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150812  2:27:48 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150812  2:27:48 [ERROR] Aborting

150812  2:27:48 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150812  2:27:49 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150812  2:27:49 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150812  2:27:49 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150812  2:27:49 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150812  2:27:49 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150812  2:27:49 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
InnoDB: mmap(274726912 bytes) failed; errno 12
150812  2:27:49 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150812  2:27:49 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
150812  2:27:49 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150812  2:27:49 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150812  2:27:50 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150812  2:27:50 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: You haven't got enough memory.

Answer (score 1):

The bit that says "Fatal error" is usually a good indication, "Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool", however that appears to be a startup message, not a shutdown message.  In fact, nothing in that log suggests that the server has been running for a period and then shut down.  Given that you say the server shuts down at midnight, you might want to look at logs for around that time, rather than at 2:27.

Comment: I'm sorry for using ambiguous word. The service did stop on 2:27 (I've got the mail about cannot connect to database log on that time.)
And this is all the log that shows on that night.

Comment: Then you are, if you'll pardon my French, doomed.